# What is the best practice for reading a large number of custom settings from a text file?

Tags: java, file-handling

So I have been looking through some code I wrote a few years ago for an economic simulation program. Each simulation has a large number of settings that can be saved to a file and later loaded back into the program to re-run the same/similar simulation. Some of the settings are optional or depend on what is being simulated.

The code to read back the parameters is basically one very large switch statement (with a few nested switch statements). I was wondering if there is a better way to handle this situation.

One line of the settings file might look like this:

```
#RA:1,MT:DiscriminatoryPriceKDoubleAuction,OF:Demo Output.csv,QM:100,NT:5000,KP:0.5 //continues...
```

And some of the code that would read that line:

```
switch( Character.toUpperCase( s.charAt(0) ) )
{
    case 'R':
         randSeed = Integer.valueOf( s.substring(3).trim() );
         break;
    case 'M':
          marketType = s.substring(3).trim();
          System.err.println("MarketType: " + marketType);
          break;
    case 'O':
          outputFileName = s.substring(3).trim() ;
          break;
    case 'Q':
          quantityOfMarkets = Integer.valueOf( s.substring(3).trim() );
          break;
    case 'N':
          maxTradesPerRound = Integer.valueOf( s.substring(3).trim() );
          break;
    case 'K':
          kParameter = Float.valueOf( s.substring(3).trim() );
          break;
 // continues...
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about serializing the object to disk, and deserializing it later?

Comment: Reinvent the wheel much? I suggest you use one of many existing formats for storing settings and then use a library. If you still decide against it, why not just parse a line into a dictionary first and then process it later? These lines are not very different from a complex combination of command line switches, if you remove commas, colons, and prefix options with a'-'. Ideally your program can take args on command line or read them from a settings file and work the same way. *nix tools do this. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c

Answer (score 7):

From a code perspective, the cleanest method would be to switch to the [`Properties` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). It's made for handling this, although you would either need to define all of your settings (even the unused ones) in the file it reads from or have predefined constants in a source file that you can use if the properties file returns null for a particular named property.

If you can't change the scheme, you could follow the general strategy of having a `Hashtable`, which is really what the Properties class does - it reads a file into a `Hashtable` conveniently. It would pretty much be rolling your own properties. Again, you would have to have preset values defined somehow to handle cases where a setting that you need might not exist in the file.

The way you would use either is to simply query the data structure any time you needed a value. You can either enforce that it exists in the data structure (throw an Exception and terminate it it doesn't) or define default values somehow (probably in a source file).

Answer (score 3):

An excellent library for this sort of work is [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/)

> provides a generic configuration interface which enables a Java application to read configuration data from a variety of sources. Commons Configuration provides typed access to single, and multi-valued configuration parameters as demonstrated by the following code:
>
> ```
>     Double double = config.getDouble("number");
>     Integer integer = config.getInteger("number");
> ```
>
> Configuration parameters may be loaded from the following sources:
>
> - Properties files
> - XML documents
> - Windows INI files
> - Property list files (plist)
> - JNDI
> - JDBC Datasource
> - System properties
> - Applet parameters
> - Servlet parameters
>
> Different configuration sources can be mixed using a `ConfigurationFactory` and a `CompositeConfiguration`. Additional sources of configuration parameters can be created by using custom configuration objects. This customization can be achieved by extending `AbstractConfiguration` or `AbstractFileConfiguration`.
>
> The full Javadoc API documentation is available [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/index.html)...

Comment: yes properties is only string  but this is numbers, dates and from different formats. neat

Answer (score 0):

Almost every decent application and framework I know uses XML to store configurations.

I would suggest that you create a configuration class if you use java. Then you can use JAXB to annotate and serialize this class. After that, reading and writing the XML file via model is a simple thing to do.